# Printed document size is scaled down in an electron.js wrapped react application

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have a reactjs application which needs to print receipts on a very specific paper. Each receipt has a 5.79" x 3.23" printable surface which is configured in CSS within our application as a printable div within a containing page. Printing from the application running in a standard browser is working fine, using a simple window.print();  and a test border applied to the edge of the printed DIV is displaying as expected.

When I try to run the same app wrapped with electron the printed output is scaled down significantly. If I increase my CSS to push the container div to 7.25" x 3.2" I can see the contents approximately fill the expected area.

Is there a known scale down when printing through electron or a setting I can adjust within either the BrowserWindow or webContents?  To try and resolve this we did try modifying settings in electron.remote

```
const { remote } = window.require("electron");
var options = {
    silent: false,
    printBackground: true,
    color: false,
    margins: {
        marginType: "none", //No setting here seems to make a difference
    },
    copies: 1,
}
remote.getCurrentWindow().webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => {
    if (!success) console.log(failureReason);
});
```